# jsf 2.0 Primefaces multiple Fileupload does not remember uploaded files

Tags: ajax, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces, drag-and-drop

I already have fixed some other issues (fileuploadhandler is now working) in this post, where my code is following:

**Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TempBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -70753689043016662L;
    private List<String> names; //to remember which files have been uploaded

    public void load(){
        System.out.println("@prerender");
    }

    public TempBean() {
        super();
        System.out.println("@constructor");
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void pc(){
        System.out.println("@postconstruct");
    }

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) { 
        String filename = event.getFile().getFileName();
        System.out.println("INCOMING FILE: " + filename);
        names.add(filename);

        if(!names.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Files uploaded:");
            for(String n : names){
                System.out.println("# " + n);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
   }  

    public List<String> getNames() {
        return names; 
    }

    public void setNames(List<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

}
```

**xhtml-page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

    <h:head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </h:head>

    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{tempBean.load}" />
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <p:fileUpload
                fileUploadListener="#{tempBean.handleFileUpload}"
                mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" multiple="true" update=":overview" />
        </h:form>

        <h:panelGroup id="overview">
            <ui:repeat var="file" value="#{tempBean.names}">
                #{file} <br/>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

The problem I am facing now (or the reason I open a new question), is that when I upload multiple (e.g. three) files, only one of them is appended to the empty list. when i reupload the two remaining files, again, only one of them is appended to the list.

Interesting is that the handleFileUpload(...) is invoked for each file...

Here is my console-output when I upload three files simultaniously:

```
@constructor
@postconstruct
@prerender
INCOMING FILE: test1.jpe
INCOMING FILE: test3.jpe
Files uploaded:
INCOMING FILE: test2.jpe
# test3.jpe
-END OF LIST-
Files uploaded:
# test1.jpe
Files uploaded:
# test2.jpe
-END OF LIST-
-END OF LIST-
@prerender
@prerender
@prerender
```

What can I do to make the fileupload-component run properly? is this a bug or an ajax problem?

**here is my web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" >

  <display-name>TestProjekt</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>test.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

      <context-param> 
        <description> 
        If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
        i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
        influence the HTML code.
        Default is 'true'</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
      </context-param>

      <context-param>
        <description>
        If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
        former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
        with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
        if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
        Default is 'false'
        </description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </context-param>


    <filter> 
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
            <param-value>C:\tmp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**and my faces.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0"> 

</faces-config>
```

Comment: am I the only one with this problem?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version exactly and which PF version exactly? Please don't say "JSF 2.0". This is a spec version which doesn't tell anything close about implementation being used and its (sub)version. See also among others the top section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Hi, I am currently using PF 4.0 (community download) and JSF 2.0 Apache Myfaces-2.2.0-20130426. (Tomcat 7)

Comment: Okay, how exactly does the root declaration of your `faces-config.xml` look like and what exactly do you all have declared in `web.xml` as to PrimeFaces file upload configuration?

Comment: I have updates the question with web.xml and faces.config

Comment: @Balus: did you try it?Is this the normal bevahiour? I cannot get a list with the uploaded files when I upload them together

Comment: I can only tell that this is indeed not expected behavior. But I can't tell from top of head how to fix this as I have to reproduce it myself first and have to look in PrimeFaces source. Will look if nobody else did before bounty end and if I have time/mood for this.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I would be very thankful if you can help me with this, because I am stuck with my project at this point :(. I already postet in the primefaces forum but noone has answered yet...

Comment: Hi, just tried to reproduce it using MyFaces 2.2.0 beta as currently available on http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html I couldn't reproduce it, it works just fine for me. I couldn't find the 20130426 version as you used over there, but the date indicates an early alpha version. I suggest to pick the latest available (the 2.2.0 beta) instead and give it a try.

Comment: Alternatively, try Mojarra instead of MyFaces. It works also just fine for me on Mojarra 2.2.4.

Comment: Hi, it worked with the new JSF Version! thank you, I always think that these versions are tested when they are published. now I know it better

Comment: Okay, I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in your JSF implementation MyFaces 2.2.0-20130426.

It works for me when I try MyFaces 2.2.0-beta as currently available at [myfaces.apache.org](http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html) and Mojarra 2.2.4 as currently available as [javaserverfaces.java.net](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/).

As confirmed by comments on the question, it then also works for you.