# Primefaces File Upload Multiple working like single

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a fileUpload in multiple mode:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{perosnaDesapBean.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced"        dragDropSupport="false"
 multiple="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
 label="Elegir Imágenes"
 cancelLabel="Cancelar"
 uploadLabel="Subir"
 update="messages"
/>
```

And in my managed bean had the handle:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {      
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

For the first uploaded file show the message, but for the second one nothing. It runs the event handler once.

My web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
  <param-value>auto</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

My managed bean is @ConversationScoped, may be why? I'm using PF: 5.1

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to the the question : I can see this context param (`primefaces.UPLOADER`) still wonky these days (along with PrimeFaces 5.1). It does not work for me along with other param values I already attempted alternatively (such as `commons`, `native`).

Comment: What version of JSF do you have? May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301314/jsf-2-0-primefaces-multiple-fileupload-does-not-remember-uploaded-files

Answer (score 0):

## Example: PF 5.1, JSF 2.2, commons-io-2.4, commons-fileupload-1.3.1

Class definition:

```
@ManagedBean ( name="fileUploadManagedBean" )
@SessionScoped
public class FileUploadManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UploadedFile fileImage;

    public UploadedFile getFileImage() {
        return fileImage;
    }

    public void setFileImage(UploadedFile fileImage) {
        this.fileImage = fileImage;
    }

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile()
                .getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

}
```

XHTML definition:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                <p:growl id="msg" />
                <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadManagedBean.fileImage}"
                                invalidSizeMessage="Size off"
                                invalidFileMessage="Type off"
                                fileLimitMessage="Only 4 files"
                                mode="advanced" multiple="true" fileLimit="4" sizeLimit="1951200"
                                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                                fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadManagedBean.handleFileUpload}"
                                update="msg" />
</h:form>
```

WEB.XML definition

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>
  org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
 </filter-class>
 <init-param>
             <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
             <param-value>1951200</param-value>
       </init-param>
       <init-param>
             <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
             <param-value>/tmpImages</param-value>
       </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include some explanation about what you are doing.