# Primefaces 5.2 Fileupload does not remember filenames

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

This question is almost the same as the following [problem described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301314/jsf-2-0-primefaces-multiple-fileupload-does-not-remember-uploaded-files). The difference is that I already updated my JSF implementation and I still getting the same behavior. In my case, what could be causing the list is not keeping the previous uploaded names?

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2 Community edition, Glassfish4 and Mojarra 2.2.12  the most current version of 2.2.x branch in the moment this question is being created.

```
2015-08-08T20:41:42.748-0400|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context '/Pack_Encrypt'
2015-08-08T20:41:44.630-0400|INFO: Monitoring jndi:/server/Pack_Encrypt/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
2015-08-08T20:41:44.666-0400|INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 5.2
```

If I may, I would like to show you my configuration files and my code.

- **FileMultipleBean:**

```java
    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class FileMultipleBean implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1672580425686966809L;
        private List<String> names;



        public FileMultipleBean() {
            super();
            System.out.println("@constructor");
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void pc(){
            System.out.println("@postconstruct");
        }

        public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) { 
            String filename = event.getFile().getFileName();
            System.out.println("INCOMING FILE: " + filename);
            names.add(filename);

            if(!names.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("Files uploaded:");
                for(String n : names){
                    System.out.println("# " + n);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        public List<String> getNames() {
            return names; 
        }

        public void setNames(List<String> names) {
            this.names = names;
        }

    }
```

- **xhtml-page:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <h:head></h:head>
   <h:body>

      <h:form>
          <p:fileUpload  
                     fileUploadListener="#{fileMultipleBean.handleFileUpload}" 
                     mode="advanced" 
                     dragDropSupport="false"
                     multiple="true"
                         update="messages" 
                         sizeLimit="100000" 
                         fileLimit="3" 
                         allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|txt)$/" 
          />

          <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
      </h:form>      
   </h:body>

   <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false">
       <p:graphicImage name="images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
   </p:dialog>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      function start() {
          PF('statusDialog').show();
      }


      function stop() {
          PF('statusDialog').hide();
      }
   </script>
</html>
```

Here is my console-output when I upload three files simultaneously, you will see that files are not kept in the list:

**Console Output**

```
2015-08-08T20:43:23.468-0400|INFO: @constructor
2015-08-08T20:43:26.182-0400|INFO: @constructor
2015-08-08T20:43:32.350-0400|INFO: @postconstruct
2015-08-08T20:43:40.868-0400|INFO: @constructor
2015-08-08T20:43:44.213-0400|INFO: @postconstruct
2015-08-08T20:43:54.936-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: PKG_AUDIT.txt
2015-08-08T20:43:59.483-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-08T20:44:02.985-0400|INFO: # PKG_AUDIT.txt
2015-08-08T20:44:13.391-0400|INFO: @postconstruct
2015-08-08T20:44:19.255-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: PKG_AUDIT_ALERT.txt
2015-08-08T20:44:20.654-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-08T20:44:22.886-0400|INFO: # PKG_AUDIT_ALERT.txt
2015-08-08T20:44:31.806-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: Test SQL.txt
2015-08-08T20:44:39.194-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-08T20:44:41.946-0400|INFO: # Test SQL.txt
```

**My Web.xml file looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Pack_Encrypt</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>


  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**And my faces.config like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

If I change the `@ViewScoped` for `@SessionScoped` the first time I load the `index.xhtml` page and upload three files, the behavior is the same, then if I refresh the page and try again, the list is going to contain the last item from the first attempt and the other three, check the next console output:

**First Upload**

```
2015-08-10T10:15:53.530-0400|INFO: @postconstruct
2015-08-10T10:15:53.604-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: PKG_AUDIT.txt
2015-08-10T10:15:54.506-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-10T10:15:54.506-0400|INFO: # PKG_AUDIT.txt
2015-08-10T10:15:55.606-0400|INFO: @postconstruct
2015-08-10T10:15:56.149-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: PKG_AUDIT_ALERT.txt
2015-08-10T10:15:56.587-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-10T10:15:56.587-0400|INFO: # PKG_AUDIT_ALERT.txt
2015-08-10T10:15:57.038-0400|INFO: @postconstruct
2015-08-10T10:15:57.449-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: Test SQL.txt
2015-08-10T10:15:57.989-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-10T10:15:57.989-0400|INFO: # Test SQL.txt
```

---

**Second Upload**

```
2015-08-10T10:25:06.850-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: 1.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:09.215-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-10T10:25:11.119-0400|INFO: # Test SQL.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:11.999-0400|INFO: # 1.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:15.939-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: 2.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:16.488-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-10T10:25:16.488-0400|INFO: # Test SQL.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:16.488-0400|INFO: # 1.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:16.488-0400|INFO: # 2.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:16.888-0400|INFO: INCOMING FILE: 3.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:17.189-0400|INFO: Files uploaded:
2015-08-10T10:25:17.189-0400|INFO: # Test SQL.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:17.189-0400|INFO: # 1.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:17.189-0400|INFO: # 2.txt
2015-08-10T10:25:17.189-0400|INFO: # 3.txt
```

I've checked cookies, as @BalusC suggested, the following description have data that may helps, `39` is the size, Domain, Path, Expires/Max-Age are set as `N/A`:

```
Request Cookies                 39              
JSESSIONID  7f6179234f8ec0b82e482901bfff    N/A N/A N/A 39  

Response                        0
```

Comment: In other words, the bean is not view scoped, but behaves like request scoped. Which package did you import `@ViewScoped` from? There are two. One for JSF managed beans and one for CDI managed beans. By the way, never use constructor for bean property initialization. Use post construct for that only.

Comment: Hello @BalusC,

I imported this two packages:

    `import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;`
    `import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;`

Comment: Okay. What if you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<h:form>` as indicated in `<p:fileUpload>` documentation?

Comment: I added  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and I'm using `@PostConstruct` method to initialize the list **`names`** as you suggested as well. I'm still getting the same behavior. I'm following this  [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml), the multiple file upload doc.

Comment: I also experimented changing the `@ViewScoped` to `@SessionScoped`, but without luck, the behavior is still the same one.

Comment: Ah, that hints another possible cause: HTTP session isn't maintained. This is normally to be done via `JSESSIONID` cookie. Can you confirm this based on HTTP traffic? (press F12 in browser, Network panel, check response/request cookies)

Comment: Hello @BallusC, I added to the post the `JSESSIONID` cookie, it looks ok from my understanding.